# Angular Module Federation -- Shared module is not available for eager consumption

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack-module-federation

Getting this issue when trying to run tests on my Angular microfrontend to use inside Module Federation. Angular 12, Webpack 5.

`Uncaught Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: 5487`

How to configure eager consumption for these modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a separate webpack.conf for testing**

You can set all shared modules to `eager: true` in your primary `webpack.config.js`, but that would force you to use a larger bundle size, one of the things Module Federation aims to avoid.

A better option could be to set up a separate `webpack.test.config.js,` which will just be used for running tests, and in that file set your modules to `eager: true`:

**webpack.test.config.js**

```
shared: share({
  "@angular/core": { 
    eager: true, 
    singleton: true, 
    strictVersion: true, 
    requiredVersion: 'auto' 
  },
  "@angular/common": { 
    eager: true, 
    singleton: true, 
    strictVersion: true, 
    requiredVersion: 'auto' 
  },
  "@angular/common/http": { 
    eager: true, 
    singleton: true, 
    strictVersion: true, 
    requiredVersion: 'auto' 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, solve this issue by setting `eager: true` on your shared common Angular modules:

```
        
shared: share({
  "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', eager: true },
  "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', eager: true },
  "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', eager: true },
  "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', eager: true },
```